Generate AuthnRequestsSigned and WantAssertionsSigned in metadata spring security saml2 v6.4.1
I have to create the integration of the application I'm developping to an existent SSO which I don't controll it.
In the last project, i was using
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

and:
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml-dsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

Among other dependencies.
And in relaying party generated metadata file, I could see:
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">


But now we decided to upgrade to:
<spring-boot.version> 3.4.0-M3
<spring-security-saml2-core.version> 2.0.0.M31
<spring-security-saml-dsl-core.version> 1.0.5.RELEASE
<spring-security-saml2-service-provider.version> 6.4.0-M4

I have done what says in Spring SAML2 documentation i. e.:
This is my SecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig{
    private static final String SAML_METADATA = "/saml/metadata";

    @Autowired
    PmaLdapValidationHandler pmaLdapValidationHandler;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http
            .saml2Metadata((saml2) -> saml2.metadataUrl(SAML_METADATA))
            .saml2Login(withDefaults()).saml2Logout(withDefaults())
            .logout(withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated());
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }
}


This is my application.yml:
logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security.saml2: DEBUG

spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /templates/
      suffix: .pug
    static-path-pattern: /static/**

  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          pma_web:
            entity-id: "${sso.entity-id}"
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: classpath:saml/credentials/rp-private.key
                  certificate-location: classpath:saml/credentials/rp-certificate.crt
            singlelogout:
              binding: POST
              url: "{baseUrl}/logout/saml2/slo"
            assertingparty:
              metadata-uri: classpath:saml/${env}/metadata.xml

  datasource:
    jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/pma_web
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

pma-cmdb:
  pma-keystore-key-alias: pma-jwt-signing-key
  pma-keystore-password: pma-jwt-p422w0rd


But now, such attributes, have gone away:
<md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">

I have tried almost everything to generate those attributes, but I couldn't by now.
How could I do it?

I, finally, found a way.
In the SecurityConfig.java file, you have to customize the metadata response resolver this way:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig{
    private static final String SAML_METADATA = "/saml/metadata";

    @Autowired
    PmaLdapValidationHandler pmaLdapValidationHandler;

    @Autowired
    RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        var metadataResolver = new OpenSaml4MetadataResolver();
        metadataResolver.setEntityDescriptorCustomizer(edParameters -> {
            var spssoDescriptor
            = edParameters.getEntityDescriptor().getSPSSODescriptor(SAMLConstants.SAML20P_NS);

            spssoDescriptor.setAuthnRequestsSigned(true);
            spssoDescriptor.setWantAssertionsSigned(true);
        });

        var responseResolver
        = new RequestMatcherMetadataResponseResolver(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository, metadataResolver);

        responseResolver.setRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(SAML_METADATA));

        // @formatter:off
        http
            .saml2Metadata((saml2) -> saml2.metadataResponseResolver(responseResolver))
            .saml2Login(withDefaults()).saml2Logout(withDefaults())
            .logout(withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated());
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }
}

This way produces the attributes in the SPSSODescriptor:
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
Note that '.saml2Metadata((saml2) -> saml2.metadataUrl(SAML_METADATA))' line is deleted because the responseResolver, overwrite the metadataUrl previously defined.
Note also, that this not ensure the assertions/authentications be signed, this has to be configured too in the future.
Hope it helps.
